# How to troubleshoot CiviRules triggers?

Tags: civirules

I have just installed CiviRules 1.12 on CiviCRM 4.7.14. I tried to create a few simple test rules, but none of them worked. I suspect I might have to look for solution somewhere else.

```
Trigger: Contribution is changed 
Linked Condition: Contact in group TEST
Linked Action: Remove contact from group: TEST
```

[image]

I also tried a few similar Rules, e.g.:

- IF Contribution is added THEN remove from Group.
- IF Tag is added THEN remove from Group.
- IF contact is removed from group THEN display the Message.

All were set to run IMMEDIATELY without delay.

What might have gone wrong? Something with setup or configuration? I did not see anything unusual.

---

### UPDATE:

Upon further tests the issue was narrowed down to a single CiviRules action, namely, **Remove contact from group**.

Answer (score 4):

I would as a test forget about the display message first, and start only with adding to and removing from group. I would expect those to work.

I have just tested a rule on my CiviCRM 4.7.15 local install as in the screen print that I have attached, and that works fine? Can you test with the same rule?

[image]

Comment: After a series of tests, I can conclude that I was missing the refresh button. Actions like Add Tag, Remove Tag, Add to Group, Display Message work fine, however, there is a problem with the **Remove contact from Group** Action.

Comment: Created new issue https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/issues/144. I will try to have a look in the next few days.